# Books that deals with finding polynomials satisfying given conditions.

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am a student and gave my 10 grade exam last month. I am preparing for Mathematics Olympiads. I saw some questions regarding finding polynomials that satisfy some equation or condition. For e.g.

Find all polynomials such that $P(x^2+1)=P(x)^2+1$

I am looking for some book that would be available online in pdf format that shows how to solve  such problems from very basic that I can understand. I have never solved such problems. I have looked on some solutions but I am not able to understand them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would start with $$p(x)=ax+b$$

Comment: Ed. Barbeau, *Polynomials* has many exercises. Faddeev - Sominsky *Problems in Higher Algebra* also has many.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That will drop most of the solutions. Note that the equation is of the form $P\circ f=f\circ P$.

Comment: @deyore thank you for these books. The first one is great, the second one is little beyond my level. I there any book that explicitly shows step by step ways of solving problems mentioned in the post.

Comment: Probably. There are many books on problem solving and for competitions. Some of them might have a section on polynomials. That particular problem has been asked here before. With a bit of luck and patience you might be able to find it. By the way, the second book is mostly high-school algebra. Many of the problems are properties and ideas that are useful in competitions.